# The total of the player placing 2 was?

Tags: combinatorics

> 8 players compete in a tournament,every one plays everyone else just once. The winner of the game gets 1, the loser 0 or, each gets $\frac{1}{2}$ if draw. The final result is that every one gets a different score and the player placing second gets the same score as the total of the four bottom players.
>
> "The total of the player placing 2 was?"

I can do it if the case where a draw can happen is neglected.But I'm stuck with this one...Help!

Answer (score 7):

Let $s_1<s_2\dots < s_8$ be the $8$ scores of players $1,2,3\dots 8$.

Notice $s_7=s_1+s_2+s_3+s_4\geq\binom{4}{2}=6$ (because there are $6$ games between players $1,2,3,4$)

$s_7=6$ is possible, it happens when player $i$ beats player $j$ if $i>j$.

The maximum score for a person is $7$, notice $s_7=6.5$ is impossible, because $s_8$ would have to be $7$ and these scores are mutually exclusive, $s_7=7$ is also clearly impossible.

Comment: I believe this is the intended solution.  Well done.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple answer is possible if you assume the question is well posed and has a unique answer. As you imply, if there are no draws and everybody gets a different score, the second ranked player gets a score of $6$, which equals the sum of the bottom four players at $0,1,2,3$.  As this result meets the requirement, if there is a unique result it is $6$.  We have not proven that this is the only result possible.